# If $(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2(x+z-1)$, then show that $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is constant and find its numeric value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, problem-solving

I am trying to solve this question,

> If $(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2(x+z-1)$, then show that $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is constant and find its numeric value.

I've tried this, 
$$x^2-2x + z^2-2z + 2 + y^2 = 0$$
$$ (x-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 + y^2 = 0$$

The left hand side can only become $0$ if $x=1$, $y=0$ and $z=1$, so the only solution is $x=z=1$ and $y=0$, which gives $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 2$.

> - Have I solved it correctly?
> - And is there any other method to solve it?

Comment: Your question is correct. Your method is the most simple, (I think that)

Comment: One of your $2x$'s should be a $2z$ above, though, and this is only true if $x,y,z$ are real numbers.

Comment: @CarlHeckman I corrected it. Is it also true for complex numbers?

Comment: It does not work for complex numbers. Take $(x,y,z) = (2,1,i)$ and $(x,y,z) = (0,1,i)$. In both cases $(x-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 + y^2  = 0$, but $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ is equal to $9 -i$ in the first case and to $1-i$ in the latter case.

Comment: Yeah because squares of complex numbers can be negative making various solutions possible. In the exam they did not mention whether x,y and z were real or not.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> The left hand side can only become $0$ if $x=1$, $y=0$ and $z=1$, so the only solution is $x=z=1$ and $y=0$, which gives $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 2$.

I would add a justification that these values for $x$, $y$, and $z$ are unique.

We know that each of the three terms, $(x-1)^2$, $(z-1)^2$ and $y^2$ are positive *if we are dealing with Real Numbers*. So, if any of them were non-zero, then at least one of the other terms would have to be negative for the equation to equal $0$. *If we are dealing with Real Numbers*, that is not possible. So each term *must* equal $0$.

Once that justification is taken into account, including the assumption that ${x,y,z}\in \mathbb R$, then I think the OP has made a sound demonstration.

Comment: Yes you are right x,y and z have to be real. E.g. if they are complex then the squared stuff could become negative.